Wordpress multisite w/subdomain and subdirectory
I have a wordpress multisite with following subdomain structure.

https://admin.example.com
https://example.com
https://sub1.example.com
https://sub2.example.com

Now that I'd like to have a few subdirectories to example.com, but I do not like to share user base. So, instead of adding new subdirectories to the existing multisite, I'd like to install a new wordpress with following structure.

https://admin2.example.com
https://example.com/dir1
https://example.com/dir2
https://example.com/dir3

I already have my Nginx set up for subdomain case, like
server_name *.example.com example.com;
root /var/www/websites/example

along with location parameters for subdomain.
Now, I believe I should have another set of server_name and location parameters for the 2nd installation, as I am not able to access the subdirectory subsites.
I've checked with another thread for a single installation with WP Multi Network, but I strictly prefer to keep the user base separated, so looking for two WP installation options.
